# Filtering multiple conditions through associated objects using ransack

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am using Ransack to provide data filters.

The main User model has the following association:
`user has_many trips, through registrations`

The basic search conditions such as `user's name=xyz and trip's name=abc` works fine.

But most of our conditions work on negation, such as `user's name=xyz and trip's name=abc and trip's name != def` doesn't work as expected.

We are trying to find people who have gone on ABC trip, but not on DEF trip.  But the SQL generated for the above query generates this clause: `WHERE (trips.name LIKE 'ABC') AND (trips.name NOT LIKE 'DEF')`.  This obviously doesn't work as the users table is left-inner-joined with this clause and the trip.ids are generated for rows with name like ABC and not like DEF.

How does one do this using Ransack?

UPDATE:

If the search query is "Users who have gone on trip named 'ABC'", the SQL generated is fine:
`SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations ON registrations.user_id = users.id LEFT OUTER JOIN trips ON trips.id = registrations.batch_id WHERE (trips.name LIKE '%ABC%')`

If the search query is "Users who have gone on trips 'ABC' and 'DEF'", how does one do it?  I tried two different approaches:

1. Two separate conditions with name = 'ABC' and name = 'DEF'.  This was done with "matches all".  The SQL gave 0 results (obviously) as this was generated:
   `SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations ON registrations.user_id = users.id LEFT OUTER JOIN trips ON trips.id = registrations.batch_id WHERE ((trips.name LIKE '%ABC%' AND trips.name LIKE '%DEF%'))`
2. I tried "matches any" instead.  That gave this:
   `SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations ON registrations.user_id = users.id LEFT OUTER JOIN trips ON trips.id = registrations.batch_id WHERE ((trips.name LIKE '%ABC%' OR trips.name LIKE '%DEF%'))`

The 2nd query results were those users who had either gone on ABC or DEF.

To add to this, we wanted this query: "Users who have gone on ABC but not on DEF".  I tried this with two conditions (matches all): trip.name = ABC and trips.name not like DEF.  This was the SQL generated:
`SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations ON registrations.user_id = users.id LEFT OUTER JOIN trips ON trips.id = registrations.batch_id WHERE ((trips.name LIKE '%ABC%' AND trips.name NOT LIKE '%DEF%'))`

The above query returned people who had gone on trip ABC.  It didn't filter out people who had done DEF as the query is obviously wrong.

Comment: Hi, can you please share the whole search filter condition here, then i can help you better way.

Comment: I've updated the original question with the search filters.

Comment: Yes, this query firstly check the name with 'ABC' and then check on result data that trip's name should not 'DEF' so i think that this query is right.

Comment: I agree that the last query is correct.  But, if my use-case is to search for "Users who have gone on ABC but not on DEF", how do I do it using Ransack?

Comment: Sorry for kicking this, but did you solve this with Ransack? I'm looking for a solution for the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Users who have been on trip 'ABC' but not on 'DEF':

`User.ransack(trips_name_eq: 'ABC', trips_name_not_eq: 'DEF').results`